# Sort products in ascending order by name on specific category page not working

Tags: magento2, sorting, category-listing, product-sorting

I want to sort product for a specific category by name in ascending order but it is still sorting in descending order in the front-end.

For a category under Display Setting, I have set `Default Product Listing Sort By` to `Product Name`

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
  <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
          <action method="setDefaultDirection">
              <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">asc</argument>
            </action>
  </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Here is how it looks.

[image]

I have checked the setting in all store view and I have the same setting.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: may be It can be an indexing issue.did you reindexed or not ?

Comment: @SavanPatel I already tried that and it did not work.

Comment: try below code , hope it useful

Comment: I have just tried it in my localhost without putting the code in the Design section's layout Update XML. I found it working fine. Please check https://nimb.ws/1J9mKv and https://nimb.ws/x3MHPz

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">asc</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
```

It's working for my side